# MQTT cannot connect by configuration

Tags: java, spring, mqtt

I want to receive mqtt messages that's why I used a spring implementation for mqtt including paho library and mosquito brocker.

The problem is that everything functions very well when I test mqtt channel locally (on my own pc). But when I transport the configuration to the server and start testing there, I receive an exception

```
ERROR taskScheduler-1 inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter:289 - Exception while connecting and subscribing Client is disconnected (32101)
```

What could be the reason of this behaviour?

My config file looks like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("${configuration.properties.path}")
@ComponentScan({"package.1", "package.2", "package.3"})    
@IntegrationComponentScan({"package.1", "package.2"})  
@EnableIntegration
public class TransportMqttConfigBean {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Bean
public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory(){       
    return new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();      
}   

@Bean
@Description("Channel for mqtt messages that leave outbound adapter (should be received)")
public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();     
}

@Bean
@Description("Channel for mqtt messages that come into inbound adapter (should be sent)")
public MessageChannel mqttOutputChannel() {     
    return new DirectChannel();
}   

@Bean
@Description("Channel for mqtt messages with payload")
public MessageChannel mqttGeneralChannel() {        
    return new DirectChannel();
}   

@Bean
@Description("Channel for mqtt errors")
public MessageChannel mqttErrorChannel() {      
    return new DirectChannel();
}   

@Bean
@Description("mqtt inbound adapter: receives mqtt messages")
public MessageProducer mqttInboundAdapter() {
    log.info("creating mqtt inbound adapter");
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
            new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    env.getProperty("mqtt.hostname")+":" +env.getProperty("mqtt.port"), 
                    "name",
                    "#");
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
    adapter.setErrorChannel(mqttErrorChannel());
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
@Description("mqtt outbound adapter: sends mqtt messages")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutputChannel")
public MessageHandler mqttOutboundAdapter() {
    log.info("creating mqtt outbound adapter");
    MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler =
                   new MqttPahoMessageHandler(
                           env.getProperty("mqtt.hostname")+":" +env.getProperty("mqtt.port"), 
                           "name2", 
                           mqttClientFactory());
    messageHandler.setAsync(true);
    messageHandler.setDefaultTopic("escosTopic");
    return messageHandler;
}

@Bean 
public ApplicationListener<?> applicationListener(){
      ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer producer=new ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer();
      producer.setEventTypes(MqttConnectionFailedEvent.class);
      producer.setOutputChannel(mqttErrorChannel());
      return producer;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is your MQTT Server you are trying to connect password protected? What is the port it is listening on? Is it behind a Firewall?

Comment: no password, standard port, with firewall (as i think)

Comment: port number is 1883

Comment: Has firewall opened the port 1883 for incoming traffic?

Comment: yes. at least i used 'ufw allow 1883/tcp' command to do it.

Comment: Try to connect to MQTT server at iot.eclipse.org and 1883 with your code and check whether it works. And Telnet to your MQTT server and see whether you can connect

Answer (score 0):

ClientId of Mqtt subscriber must be unique. It happens because two your subscribers have same client id. First runs on your local machine, second on your server. Second gets disconnected from Mqtt broker.

In your code you did it that way

```
MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler =
                   new MqttPahoMessageHandler(
                           env.getProperty("mqtt.hostname")+":" +env.getProperty("mqtt.port"), 
                           "name2", 
                           mqttClientFactory());
```

See you called it "name2"
Try to use that snippet

```
String url = env.getProperty("mqtt.hostname") + ":" + env.getProperty("mqtt.port");
String clientId = "subAt" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler =
                new MqttPahoMessageHandler(url,clientId,mqttClientFactory());
```

It adds to clientId hostname of machine that runs your soft.